# Mantis - Add version field

Tags: version, field, mantis

Is it possible to have a version number for each defect/issue raised in [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org) and track its value during the lifetime of the defect?

e.g 
v0.1 - Issue reported 
v0.2 - Issue assigned
v0.5 - Issue resolved
v0.6 - Issue closed

I have never used custom fields in Mantis - can they be employed for such a purpose?

UPDATE:

In the meantime, I found these references:

1. [Custom Fields](http://manual.mantisbt.org/manual.customizing.mantis.custom.fields.php)
2. [Manage Custom Fields](http://manual.mantisbt.org/manual.page.descriptions.system.management.pages.manage.custom.fields.php)

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 version fields in MantisBT 1.2

- Product Version - in which version does the issue occur
- Target Version - when the issue is expected to be fixed (i.e. roadmap)
- Fixed in Version - when the issue was actually fixed (i.e. changelog)

Not sure if this is really what you are asking for.

Also note that each change to any field is tracked in a history record which provides a full audit of changes made throughout the issues' lifecycle.